# Removing the title bar make the entire app background look black

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

I need to remove the `ActionBar` from my entire application, so I added `Theme.NoTitleBar` to my code in manifest.

Following is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.beleeta.bileetacrm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.beleeta.bileetacrm.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But, this make the entire application background to look black! Before I make this change, the application was white, and below was the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.beleeta.bileetacrm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.beleeta.bileetacrm.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why is this happening? How can I get rid of this? This is the first time I am dealing with these action bars.

My min SDK is 11.

Answer (score 4):

The default `Theme` (and hence, `Theme.NoTitleBar`) are dark themes - you can use `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` for a light (i.e., while background) theme.

Comment: Simple and straightforward!  No clumsy things in code this way...  This should become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` from Manifest file. and add this

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

to every class before you did setcontentview.